# Add parameter value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, rss

I am using an RSS feed to get the latest headlines for sports teams and I wanted to parameterize the team name to append to the following script.  In the example below the team abbreviation is ATL.  I need to change ATL to other team abbreviations such as NE, NYG, etc..There will be 20+ options.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedbucket.com/js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nfl.com%2Frss%2Frsslanding%3FsearchString%3Dteam%26abbr%3DATL&chan=y&desc=1&date=y" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I try the following code in the BODY of the page then the feed doesn't get recongnzied and causes an error.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedbucket.com/js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nfl.com%2Frss%2Frsslanding%3FsearchString%3Dteam%26abbr%3D"+ teamName  + "&chan=y&desc=1&date=y" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas on how to parametrize the team value so that I don't have to create hidden DIV tags to represent each team?

Comment: `src` is an html attribute. it's not javascript, and cannot execute any javascript like your `+ teamName +` string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea on how to make the src value dynamic within the BODY or how to call the script in the BODY?  I'm stuck on that I can't add additional JavaScript to do the business logic that I want.

Comment: you'd have to insert a separate `<script>` for each team. I'm not sure how all browsers would react if you change the `src` of one `<script>` repeatedly - would they nuke any code/vars defined by the "old" version of that script tag, or would the new code load up without any trouble.

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right path.  I changed my code to use a Google RSS feed reader and now I'm able to parameterize it with code such as:    
    getOnlineFeed('http://www.nfl.com/rss/rsslanding?searchString=team&abbr=' + localStorage.getItem("A4CTeamId"));